# Flowtype with standard Failed to load plugin flowtype--parser

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eslint, flowtype

[image]

#### Installed on `package.json`

```
"babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.1",
"flow-bin": "^0.55.0",
"flow-typed": "2.1.5",
"standard-flow": "^1.0.0",
"babel-eslint": "8.0.0",
"eslint": "^4.7.1",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.1",
```

> Error: Failed to load plugin flowtype--parser: Cannot find module
>   'eslint-plugin-flowtype--parser'
>
> Error: Failed to load plugin flowtype--parser: Cannot find module
>   'eslint-plugin-flowtype--parser'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
>       at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)

### My stantard configuration ..

```
 "standard": {
    "ignore": [
      "/flow-type/**/*"
    ],
    "env": [
      "mocha"
    ],
    "globals": [
      "fetch"
    ],
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": [
      "plugin:flowtype/recommended"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "flowtype"
    ]
  },
```

### Even when I run in console...

```
npx standard --fix | snazzy && npx flow
....
.../flow-typed/npm/sinon_vx.x.x.js
  203:27  error  '$Exports' is not defined
  206:27  error  '$Exports' is not defined
  209:27  error  '$Exports' is not defined
  ... // MORE ..
```

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your error but you have `"eslint-plugin-flowtype"` listed twice in `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-flowtype--parser'

Two dashes must be a typo. Anyway, one should use `babel-eslint` as the parser and `eslint-plugin-flowtype` as one of the plugins.

Yep, all these eslint/babel/flowtype plugins and configs might be confusing. You can go through all of their readme's...

Or you can take a look at final config [here](https://github.com/amankkg/node-api-ideas/blob/master/.eslintrc), as example.